# Infiltrate the Imposter Ring

Tags: word, wordplay, pattern, connect-wall

POWER has arrived late to the puzzle, and another word has stolen its place! Who is the imposter?

[image: MAN, I, DON, DESCEND, BACK, OUT, BIT, OR, HOUSE, FALL, TEN, WORK, SLAUGHTER, WATER, ANT, CON. The word POWER is also shown, off to the side.]

Notes:

This style of puzzle (connect-wall) requires you to group 16 words into four groups of four.

I think this puzzle has a more well-defined solution than [my last connect-wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125820/sort-25-words-into-five-groups).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The imposter is

> **SLAUGHTER**

Reason

> The words can be grouped into four groups where adjacent pairs either generate a word or phrase forming a ‘**WORD RING**’ (hence the title):

> Fall-out-back-water-(fall)
>
>  I-con-descend-ant-(I)
>
>  Man-slaughter-house-work-(man)
>
>  Don-or-bit-ten-(don)

> POWER can replace SLAUGHTER to make **MANPOWER** and **POWERHOUSE**!

Title

> The third group I listed is the ‘**IMPOSTER RING**’ !

Comment: Speedy! Nice job.

Comment: Way easier than the last one but still challenging enough to be fun!